# Как перетащить данные из одномерного массива в двумерный

Tags: java

Не могу понять в чём ошибка, при компиляции  ТNeatBeans вроде выводит нужный  результат, но пишет что сборка была завершена со сбоем. Вот полный код программы:

```
 package javaapplication37;

 public class JavaApplication37 {

   public static void main(String[] args) { 

     char[][] m = new char[6][6]; 
     char [] r = s.toCharArray ();
     String s = "ПриветМир";
     int t = 0;  
     char x = 'а';
     for (int j=0; j< 6; j++){
       for (int i =0;   i< 6; i++) {
         m[i][j]= r[t];
         t++;
         System.out.println(m[i][j]);
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: а какую ошибку выдаёт?

Comment: А что вы ожидали, пытаясь превратить массив из 9 символов в "двумерный" массив на 36 элементов? Что должно быть в ячейках 10-36?

Comment: Komdosh, выводит это : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at javaapplication37.JavaApplication37.main(JavaApplication37.java:22)
C:\Users\Александр\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
СБОРКА ЗАВЕРШЕНА СО СБОЕМ (общее время: 18 секунды)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В строке `m[i][j]= r[t];` вы обращаетесь к элементу с индексом `t`. Однако, этот индекс у Вас возрастает до 36 (6 * 6 во вложенном цикле), а входная строка `ПриветМир` всего 9(+1) символов.
Ошибка `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` говорит о обращении за пределы массива; в данном случае - `r[10]`.

Можно решить проблему:

1. Используя более длинную входную строку ( >35 символов).
2. Уменьшив размер массива m (i*j < 10).